# Object Reference compilation error when using Firebase Cloud Communication component for Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new xamarin forms app
2. Build iOS => Ensure it builds successfully
3. Add the iOS component for [Firebase Cloud Messaging for iOS](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/firebaseioscloudmessaging) from the component store
4. Clean, Rebuild => Notice you get object reference error while compiling the iOS project

Here is the error from output window:

> "src\RepeatReturns\packages\Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.2\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(25,3): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any idea how can we fix this?

Thanks

UPDATE: 
If it helps, I have the linker option for iOS set to "link SDK assemblies only".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 2017 RC, then I suggest that you stuck with Visual Studio 2015 for the moment, I had the same issue, and I didn't find any solution. So I reinstalled VS 2015, and everything is working now.